How to remove the read-only mode and signatures of a digitally signed PDF with pdfbox
From time to time we want to remove the write-protection/"encryption" and digital signatures of our PDF documents, so the document can be changed and re-signed. E.g. because the original document is missing or was changed and the digital signatures became corrupt (E.g. this document).
For this, we used the following iText 8 code (Indeed, flattening the AcroForm is not the best way, e.g. because interactive forms become disabled etc.):
public static byte[] cleanUpPdfItext(byte[] originalPdfData) throws Exception {
    // Read the PDF document
    try (
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(originalPdfData)).setUnethicalReading(true);
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter)
    ) {
        // Create the signature utils
        SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);

        // Check if encrypted and/or contains signatures
        boolean isEncrypted = pdfReader.isEncrypted();
        boolean hasSignatures = !signatureUtil.getSignatureNames().isEmpty();

        // Handle all cases
        if (isEncrypted && hasSignatures) { // Encrypted and signatures
            // Remove the signatures
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
            form.flattenFields();

            // Write the changes to the output stream, so we can read them
            pdfDocument.close();

            // Get the manipulated document
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        } else if (isEncrypted) { // Encrypted but no signatures
            // Write the changes to the output stream, so we can read them
            pdfDocument.close();

            // Get the manipulated document
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        } else { // Not encrypted/no signatures
            // Return the original document data
            return originalPdfData;
        }
    }
}

Question: What is the equivalent code to do this with pdfbox? Remove the write-protection/"encryption" and remove all existing signatures (Missing yet), so the document can be edited and resigned?
I came up with this initial version:
public static byte[] cleanUpPdfbox(byte[] original) throws Exception {
    try (
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PDDocument pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(original)
    ) {
        // Check if encrypted or read only
        AccessPermission accessPermission = pdDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission();
        boolean isEncrypted = pdDocument.isEncrypted() || accessPermission.isReadOnly();

        // Check if signatures exist
        boolean hasSignatures = false;
        PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        if (pdAcroForm != null) {
            // Get a list of all signature fields
            List<PDSignature> pdSignatures = pdDocument.getSignatureDictionaries();
            hasSignatures = !pdSignatures.isEmpty();
        }

        // Remove all security if required
        if (isEncrypted) {
            pdDocument.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
        }

        // Remove all signatures
        if (hasSignatures) {
            // TODO: Code in question
        }

        // Write the document
        pdDocument.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
}


You say yourself flattening the AcroForm is not the best way, so wouldn't it be better to ask for a way to remove the digital signatures without flattening the form instead of for equivalent code?

@mkl @K J Thanks a lot for your replies, I updated the link. Yes, removing the digital signatures would be better. How can I do this, especially if there are revisions?

If there are revisions you could cut off after the second last %%EOF. However this file doesn't use revisions. This solution removes the signature field from the fields array (in the hope that it's on the top level) and also removes it from the annotation array on the page. And removes the Perms entry from the document catalog.
    try (PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(new File("Encrypted.pdf")))
    {
        PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        
        List<PDField> oldFieldList = acroForm.getFields();
        List<PDField> newFieldList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PDField field : oldFieldList)
        {
            if (!(field instanceof PDSignatureField))
            {
                newFieldList.add(field);
            }
        }
        acroForm.setFields(newFieldList);
        for (PDPage page : doc.getPages())
        {
            List<PDAnnotation> oldAnnotationList = page.getAnnotations();
            List<PDAnnotation> newAnnotationList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (PDAnnotation ann : oldAnnotationList)
            {
                if (ann instanceof PDAnnotationWidget && ann.getCOSObject().containsKey(COSName.V))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                newAnnotationList.add(ann);
            }
            page.setAnnotations(newAnnotationList);
        }

        doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.PERMS);
        doc.save(new File("SO79055588-saved.pdf"));
    }

It might be possible that a signature is below the top level, although I can't remember having ever seen this. If you want to handle this, check whether a field is of type PDNonTerminalField and call getChildren() and then do the same for-loop as with the top level, and do this recursively.
(Update) Alternative solution that I originally made first (see mkl comment), signatures are deactivated but will still appear in the list:
try (PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(new File("Encrypted.pdf")))
{
    PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        
    for (PDField field : acroForm.getFieldTree())
    {
        if (field instanceof PDSignatureField)
        {
            ((PDSignatureField) field).setValue((PDSignature) null);
            ((PDSignatureField) field).getWidgets().get(0).setAppearance(null);
            ((PDSignatureField) field).getWidgets().get(0).setRectangle(new PDRectangle());
        }
    }
    doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.PERMS);
    doc.save(new File("SO79055588-saved.pdf"));
}


"This solution removes the signature field from the fields array (in the hope that it's on the top level) and also removes it from the annotation array on the page." - Even easier would be to just remove the V value of the signature field.

I tried that first because I'm lazy . Adobe then displayed this as an empty signature. That's why I took the time to write the response that is there now, so that it's really like the signature never existed.

Yes, empty (unsigned) signature fields should suffice for the op, shouldn't they?

Thanks a lot @tilman-hausherr and @mkl. I didn't think about filtering the fields and annotations. It took me some time, but I came up with the following version which works for my test documents. Feel free to give some input/thoughts, hopefully other developer can benefit from it :)
How does it work:

Check if the document is linearized or not.
For non-linearized documents, copy the content the beginning to the first %%EOF offset, for linearized to the second %%EOF offset. This will truncate potential revisions
Use this new content to load the document
Remove a potential do-not modify permission
Remove certification
All revisions were already removed, but the first signature could be signed with append = false, therefore modifying the original content without creating a new revision. Filter out all signature fields and signature annotations, but keep original/visible signature fields so the can be reused
Re-read the document and return the sanitized content

import org.apache.pdfbox.Loader;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PdfCleanerUtils {

    private static final String EOF_MARKER = "%%EOF";

    private static final Integer EOF_LENGTH = EOF_MARKER.length();

    // Private constructor
    private PdfCleanerUtils() {
    }

    public static byte[] sanitizePdfDocument(byte[] documentData) throws ServerException {
        // Check if linearized
        boolean isLinearized = isLinearized(documentData);

        // Get the first EOF offset for non-linearized documents and the second EOF offset for linearized documents (Quite rare)
        int offset = getOffset(documentData, isLinearized ? 2 : 1);

        // Get the original byte range
        byte[] originalPdfData = new byte[offset + EOF_LENGTH];
        System.arraycopy(documentData, 0, originalPdfData, 0, offset + EOF_LENGTH);

        // Load and parse the PDF document based on the original data we just got
        try (PDDocument pdDocument = Loader.loadPDF(originalPdfData)) {
            // Remove encryption and security protection if required
            AccessPermission accessPermission = pdDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission();
            if (!accessPermission.canModify()) {
                pdDocument.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
            }

            // Remove certification if required
            COSDictionary catalog = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
            if (catalog.containsKey(COSName.PERMS)) {
                catalog.removeItem(COSName.PERMS);
            }

            // Check for a remaining signature. This can be the case when the first signature was added with incremental = false.
            // Signatures with incremental = true were already cut away by the EOF range because we drop the revisions
            int numberOfSignatures = getNumberOfSignatures(pdDocument);
            if (numberOfSignatures > 0) {
                // Ensure there is exactly one signature. Otherwise, our EOF marker search was wrong
                if (numberOfSignatures != 1) {
                    throw new ServerException("The original document has to contain exactly one signature because it was not incrementally signed. Signatures found: " + numberOfSignatures);
                }

                // Remove the remaining signature
                removeSignatureFromNonIncrementallySignedPdf(pdDocument);
            }

            // Re-check and ensure no signatures exist
            numberOfSignatures = getNumberOfSignatures(pdDocument);
            if (numberOfSignatures != 0) {
                throw new ServerException("The original document still contains signatures.");
            }

            // Ensure the document has at least one page
            if (pdDocument.getNumberOfPages() == 0) {
                throw new ServerException("The original document has no pages.");
            }

            // Write the original document loaded by pdfbox to filter out smaller issues
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                pdDocument.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
                return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new ServerException("Unable to load the original PDF document: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isLinearized(byte[] originalPdfData) {
        // Parse the data and search for the linearized value in the first 1024 bytes
        String text = new String(originalPdfData, 0, 1024, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return text.contains("/Linearized");
    }

    private static int getOffset(byte[] originalPdfData, int markerCount) {
        // Store the number of EOF markers we passed by
        int passedMarkers = 0;

        // Iterate over all bytes and find the n.th marker. Return this as offset
        for (int offset = 0; offset < originalPdfData.length - EOF_LENGTH; offset++) {
            // Sub-search for the EOF marker
            boolean found = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < EOF_LENGTH; j++) {
                if (originalPdfData[offset + j] != EOF_MARKER.charAt(j)) {
                    // Mismatching byte, set found to false and break
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Check if the EOF marker was found
            if (found) {
                // Increase the passed markers
                passedMarkers++;

                // Check if we found our marker
                if (passedMarkers == markerCount) {
                    return offset;
                }
            }
        }

        // No EOF marker found - corrupted PDF document
        throw new RuntimeException("The PDF-document has no EOF marker - it looks corrupted.");
    }

    private static int getNumberOfSignatures(PDDocument pdDocument) {
        // Get the number of signatures
        PDAcroForm acroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        return acroForm != null ? pdDocument.getSignatureDictionaries().size() : 0;
    }

    private static void removeSignatureFromNonIncrementallySignedPdf(PDDocument pdDocument) throws IOException {
        // Get the AcroForm or return
        PDAcroForm acroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        if (acroForm == null) {
            return; // No AcroForm present
        }

        // Iterate over all fields in the AcroForm and filter out all signatures, but keep visual signature fields
        List<PDField> updatedFields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PDField field : acroForm.getFields()) {
            // Handle signature fields or just re-add the other field
            if (field instanceof PDSignatureField signatureField) {
                // Get the dictionary and the first potential widget
                COSDictionary fieldDictionary = signatureField.getCOSObject();
                PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().isEmpty() ? null : signatureField.getWidgets().getFirst();

                // Check for visibility. Only re-add signature fields and make them re-signable
                if (!isInvisible(widget)) {
                    // Clear the signature field and make it re-usable
                    fieldDictionary.removeItem(COSName.V);
                    fieldDictionary.removeItem(COSName.DV);
                    signatureField.setReadOnly(false);
                    updatedFields.add(signatureField);
                }
            } else {
                // Retain non-signature fields
                updatedFields.add(field);
            }
        }

        // Re-set the filtered AcroForm fields
        acroForm.setFields(updatedFields);

        // Iterate over all pages and their annotations and filter out all signature annotation
        for (PDPage page : pdDocument.getPages()) {
            // Filter the annotations for each page
            List<PDAnnotation> updatedAnnotations = new ArrayList<>();
            for (PDAnnotation annotation : page.getAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation instanceof PDAnnotationWidget widget) {
                    // Check if the widget belongs to an invisible signature
                    if (widget.getCOSObject().containsKey(COSName.PARENT)) {
                        COSDictionary parentField = widget.getCOSObject().getCOSDictionary(COSName.PARENT);
                        if (parentField != null && isInvisible(widget)) {
                            // Skip an invisible signature widget
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                updatedAnnotations.add(annotation); // Retain all other annotations
            }

            // Re-set the filtered annotations for the page
            page.setAnnotations(updatedAnnotations);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isInvisible(PDAnnotationWidget widget) {
        // A signature without an annotation widget is invisible
        if (widget == null) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check the rectangle for visibility. Null or width/height 0 means invisible
        PDRectangle pdRectangle = widget.getRectangle();
        return pdRectangle == null || pdRectangle.getWidth() == 0 && pdRectangle.getHeight() == 0;
    }
}

